# CSS: media queries and default css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write some css for an element with an id `#myid`, specifically for a viewport in bwetween 768 and 1024px. I have the desired css in

```
@media (max-width:1023px) and (min-width:768px){}
```

tags. My trouble is that it is getting overwritten by some css, unscoped by a media query, that comes later in the `.css` file. Because I would like there to be a default look for browsers that don't support media queries, I don't wish to wrap the unscoped css in another media query. Is there any way to avoid this problem and still keep consistent non-media query styles for browsers that don't execute `@media`?

Comment: Yes, put the unscoped CSS at the top.

Comment: @MrLister that makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a three options I can think of.

1. Move the `@media` .query to the bottom of your CSS file
2. Move your `@media` query to a separate file and import it last (after the main CSS file).
3. Add important to evey line of CSS in the `@media` query (not recommended)

Example:

```
@media (max-width:1023px) and (min-width:768px){
  body{
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
}

body{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```